# using a single UIslider as a color picker dont work

Tags: ios, uislider, uicolor

I want the user to pick a color using a single uislider to change a background on a label and I know i need to use the `colorWithHue :saturation: brightness: alpha` function and that the hue is meant to be the `slider value` and that the other are seposed to stay 1.0.

but it just don't work!!!

Can somebody help me with writing the function write?

Comment: we are not magicians.Show us the code

Comment: Also tell us what it does do and preferably tell us what debugging you've done.

Answer (score 0):

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"slider value changed:%f", sender.value);

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:sender.value saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0]
}
```

If you're using Interface Builder make sure you connect the method to the IBOutlet.

Comment: Thank you! I hate getting stuck on stuff like that. that was a great suggestion